# Transition display of login and register modal with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to animate the transition of the display of my login and register modals, I know this can't simply be done by doing `transition: display 1s`. This is why I have been using opacity since [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331353/transitions-on-the-css-display-property) has an answer where they make use of the opacity. I have been trying to implement it in my own project but it's not doing anything at the moment.

```js
function toggleRegister() {
  var register = document.getElementById("register");
  var login = document.getElementById("login");

  var registerModal = document.getElementById("registerModal");
  var loginModal = document.getElementById("loginModal");

  registerPageTitle = "Register";

  if (registerModal.style.display === "none") {
    loginModal.classList.remove("modal");
    loginModal.classList.add("modal-transition")
    loginModal.classList.add("modal-hidden");
    loginModal.classList.remove("modal-transition")
    login.style.display("none");

    registerModal.classList.remove("modal-hidden");
    registerModal.classList.add("modal-transition")
    registerModal.classList.add("modal");
    registerModal.classList.remove("modal-transition")
    register.style.display("block")

    document.title = registerPageTitle;
  } else {
    return;
  }
}

function toggleLogin() {
  var register = document.getElementById("register");
  var login = document.getElementById("login");

  var registerModal = document.getElementById("registerModal");
  var loginModal = document.getElementById("loginModal");

  loginPageTitle = "Login";

  if (loginModal.style.display === "none") {
    registerModal.classList.remove("modal");
    registerModal.classList.add("modal-transition")
    registerModal.classList.add("modal-hidden");
    registerModal.classList.remove("modal-transition")
    register.style.display("none");

    loginModal.classList.remove("modal-hidden");
    loginModal.classList.add("modal-transition")
    loginModal.classList.add("modal");
    loginModal.classList.remove("modal-transition")
    login.style.display("block");

    document.title = loginPageTitle;
  } else {
    return;
  }
}
```

```css
.header a.register {
  display: block;
  transition: color 0.2s;
}

.header a.login {
  display: none;
  transition: color 0.2s;
}

.modal-void {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 1;
}

.loginModal {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-content: flex-start;
  top: 40%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 50%;
  max-width: 500px;
  max-height: 550px;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 2.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.registerModal {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-content: flex-start;
  top: 40%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 50%;
  max-width: 500px;
  max-height: 550px;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 2.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 5px;
}


/*Modal transition*/

.modal {
  display: flex;
  opacity: 1;
}

.modal-hidden {
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
}

.modal-transition {
  display: flex;
  opacity: 0;
}

.modal-animate {
  transition: opacity 1.2s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <a class="register" id="register" onclick="toggleRegister()">Register</a>
  <a class="login" id="login" onclick="toggleLogin()">Login</a>
</div>

<div class="modal-void">
  <div class="loginModal modal-animate modal" id="loginModal">
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <form action="dashboard.html" method="post">
      <label class="userfield">
                        <input type="text" id="loginUsername" placeholder=" ">
                        <p>Username</p>
                    </label>
      <label class="userfield">
                        <input type="password" id="loginPassword" placeholder=" ">
                        <p>Password</p>
                    </label>
      <label class="button">
                        <input type="submit" id="loginSubmit" placeholder=" " value="Login">
                    </label>
      <a href="#">Password forgot?</a>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="registerModal modal-animate modal-hidden" id="registerModal">
    <h1>Register</h1>
    <form action="dashboard.html" method="post">
      <label class="userfield">
                        <input type="text" id="registerUsername" placeholder=" ">
                        <p>Username</p>
                    </label>
      <label class="userfield">
                        <input type="password" id="registerPassword" placeholder=" ">
                        <p>Password</p>
                    </label>
      <label class="userfield">
                        <input type="password" id="registerPasswordRepeat" placeholder=" ">
                        <p>Password repeat</p>
                    </label>
      <label class="button">
                        <input type="submit" id="registerSubmit" placeholder=" " value="Register">
                    </label>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

So what I am trying to do here is add and remove classes to the modals so I can transition them, although nothing happens. I'm thinking it has something to do with my CSS and JavaScript that isn't done correctly, most likely my script I suspect.

*If I forgot some code which makes this unclear, let me know and I'll add it.*

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `animation` instead:

```js
function toggleRegister() {
  var register = document.getElementById("register");
  var login = document.getElementById("login");

  var registerModal = document.getElementById("registerModal");
  var loginModal = document.getElementById("loginModal");

  registerPageTitle = "Register";

  if (registerModal.style.display === "none") {
    loginModal.classList.remove("modal");
    loginModal.classList.add("modal-transition")
    loginModal.classList.add("modal-hidden");
    loginModal.classList.remove("modal-transition")
    login.style.display("none");

    registerModal.classList.remove("modal-hidden");
    registerModal.classList.add("modal-transition")
    registerModal.classList.add("modal");
    registerModal.classList.remove("modal-transition")
    register.style.display("block")

    document.title = registerPageTitle;
  } else {
    return;
  }
}

function toggleLogin() {
  var register = document.getElementById("register");
  var login = document.getElementById("login");

  var registerModal = document.getElementById("registerModal");
  var loginModal = document.getElementById("loginModal");

  loginPageTitle = "Login";

  if (loginModal.style.display === "none") {
    registerModal.classList.remove("modal");
    registerModal.classList.add("modal-transition")
    registerModal.classList.add("modal-hidden");
    registerModal.classList.remove("modal-transition")
    register.style.display("none");

    loginModal.classList.remove("modal-hidden");
    loginModal.classList.add("modal-transition")
    loginModal.classList.add("modal");
    loginModal.classList.remove("modal-transition")
    login.style.display("block");

    document.title = loginPageTitle;
  } else {
    return;
  }
}
```

```css
.header a.register {
  display: block;
  transition: color 0.2s;
}

.header a.login {
  display: none;
  transition: color 0.2s;
}

.modal-void {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 1;
}

.loginModal {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-content: flex-start;
  top: 40%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 50%;
  max-width: 500px;
  max-height: 550px;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 2.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.registerModal {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-content: flex-start;
  top: 40%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 50%;
  max-width: 500px;
  max-height: 550px;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 2.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 5px;
}


/*Modal transition*/

.modal {
  display: flex;
  opacity: 1;
}

.modal-hidden {
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
}

.modal-transition {
  display: flex;
  opacity: 0;
}

.modal-animate {
   animation: example 1.2s;
}

@keyframes example {
    0% {opacity:0}
  100% {opacity:1}
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <a class="register" id="register" onclick="toggleRegister()">Register</a>
  <a class="login" id="login" onclick="toggleLogin()">Login</a>
</div>

<div class="modal-void">
  <div class="loginModal modal-animate modal" id="loginModal">
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <form action="dashboard.html" method="post">
      <label class="userfield">
                        <input type="text" id="loginUsername" placeholder=" ">
                        <p>Username</p>
                    </label>
      <label class="userfield">
                        <input type="password" id="loginPassword" placeholder=" ">
                        <p>Password</p>
                    </label>
      <label class="button">
                        <input type="submit" id="loginSubmit" placeholder=" " value="Login">
                    </label>
      <a href="#">Password forgot?</a>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="registerModal modal-animate modal-hidden" id="registerModal">
    <h1>Register</h1>
    <form action="dashboard.html" method="post">
      <label class="userfield">
                        <input type="text" id="registerUsername" placeholder=" ">
                        <p>Username</p>
                    </label>
      <label class="userfield">
                        <input type="password" id="registerPassword" placeholder=" ">
                        <p>Password</p>
                    </label>
      <label class="userfield">
                        <input type="password" id="registerPasswordRepeat" placeholder=" ">
                        <p>Password repeat</p>
                    </label>
      <label class="button">
                        <input type="submit" id="registerSubmit" placeholder=" " value="Register">
                    </label>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

After some more experimenting I finally got the solution.

```js
    function toggleRegister() {
        var register = document.getElementById("register");
        var login = document.getElementById("login");

        var registerModal = document.getElementById("registerModal");
        var loginModal = document.getElementById("loginModal");

        registerPageTitle = "Invictus - Registreren";
        loginPageTitle = "Invictus - Inloggen";

        if (register.style.display === "block") {
            loginModal.classList.remove("visible");
            registerModal.classList.add("visible");

            register.style.display = "none";
            login.style.display = "block";

            document.title = registerPageTitle;
        } else {
            loginModal.classList.add("visible");
            registerModal.classList.remove("visible");

            register.style.display = "block";
            login.style.display = "none";

            document.title = loginPageTitle
        }
    }

    function toggleLogin() {
        var register = document.getElementById("register");
        var login = document.getElementById("login");

        var registerModal = document.getElementById("registerModal");
        var loginModal = document.getElementById("loginModal");

        registerPageTitle = "Invictus - Registreren";
        loginPageTitle = "Invictus - Inloggen";

        if (login.style.display === "block") {
            loginModal.classList.add("visible");
            registerModal.classList.remove("visible");

            register.style.display = "block";
            login.style.display = "none";

            document.title = loginPageTitle
        } else {
            loginModal.classList.remove("visible");
            registerModal.classList.add("visible");

            register.style.display = "none";
            login.style.display = "block";

            document.title = registerPageTitle;
        }
    }
```

```css
.header a.register {
  display: block;
  transition: color 0.2s;
}

.header a.login {
  display: none;
  transition: color 0.2s;
}

.modal-void {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 1;
}

.loginModal {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;

  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-content: flex-start;

  top: 40%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);

  width: 50%;
  max-width: 500px;
  max-height: 0px;

  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 2.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);

  border-radius: 5px;

  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0;

  transition: max-height 1s 0.5s ease-out, opacity 0.5s;
}

.registerModal {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;

  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-content: flex-start;

  top: 40%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);

  width: 50%;
  max-width: 500px;
  max-height: 0px;

  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 2.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);

  border-radius: 5px;

  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0;

  transition: max-height 1s 0.5s ease-out, opacity 0.5s;
}


.visible {
  max-height: 550px;
  opacity: 1;

  transition: max-height 1s 0.5s ease-out, opacity 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <a class="register" id="register" onclick="toggleRegister()">Register</a>
  <a class="login" id="login" onclick="toggleLogin()">Login</a>
</div>

<div class="modal-void">
  <div class="loginModal visible" id="loginModal">
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <form action="dashboard.html" method="post">
      <label class="userfield">
                        <input type="text" id="loginUsername" placeholder=" ">
                        <p>Username</p>
                    </label>
      <label class="userfield">
                        <input type="password" id="loginPassword" placeholder=" ">
                        <p>Password</p>
                    </label>
      <label class="button">
                        <input type="submit" id="loginSubmit" placeholder=" " value="Login">
                    </label>
      <a href="#">Password forgot?</a>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="registerModal" id="registerModal">
    <h1>Register</h1>
    <form action="dashboard.html" method="post">
      <label class="userfield">
                        <input type="text" id="registerUsername" placeholder=" ">
                        <p>Username</p>
                    </label>
      <label class="userfield">
                        <input type="password" id="registerPassword" placeholder=" ">
                        <p>Password</p>
                    </label>
      <label class="userfield">
                        <input type="password" id="registerPasswordRepeat" placeholder=" ">
                        <p>Password repeat</p>
                    </label>
      <label class="button">
                        <input type="submit" id="registerSubmit" placeholder=" " value="Register">
                    </label>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```